# PostgreSQL: INSERT into and get the new ID for usage in LO-BASE

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sql-insert, libreoffice-base

I'd like to add a line to a table:

```
CREATE TABLE actors (
    id_act serial NOT NULL,
    first_name text NOT NULL,
    last_name text NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT actors_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_act)
); 
INSERT INTO actors (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('Tom', 'Hanks');
```

Using dBeaver, this statement provides the new ID:

```
select CurrVal(pg_get_serial_sequence('actors', 'id_act'));
```

With LibreOffice-BASE, I have to add the name of the scheme and this results in
ERROR: column "scheme_name.table_name" does not exist
I've got the same error using: 
"scheme_name.table_name"
"scheme_name"."table_name"
"table_name"

How can I get the new ID for further usage (calculation, check, ...)? I don't mind to use CurrVal or RETURNING or something else. But I don't find the proper syntax.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option is to use the `RETURNING` clause in your `INSERT` query:

```
INSERT INTO actors (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('Tom', 'Hanks') 
RETURNING id_act;
```

Comment: tried this but BASE returns an error: Type: com.sun.star.sdbc.SQLException
Message: SQL-Code provided a result, but none was expected. Found a similar example [link] (https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-insert/), last Chapter "Get the last insert id": **I need to get that "8" from there for storgae somewhere else,

Comment: @StOMicha: I don't know about BASE, but you probably need to change the method that executes the query to something that allows a return value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `insert` inside a CTE and then return the value:

```
WITH i AS (
      INSERT INTO actors (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('Tom', 'Hanks') 
          RETURNING id_act
     )
SELECT i.*
FROM i;
```

The outer query is a `SELECT`, so your UI should be comfortable with it returning a value.

You can even continue the processing in this statement -- by adding more CTEs for instance -- so you don't need to actually fetch the value.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways, which will provide you the new id's

1. Using SERIAL and PRIMARY KEY, postgres will automatically insert an unique value

   ```
      CREATE TABLE actors (
        id_act SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
        first_name text NOT NULL,
        last_name text NOT NULL
      );
   ```
2. If you have sequence, you can use this sequence while creating DDL and every time data gets inserted,
   new id will be generated

   ```
    CREATE TABLE actors (
      id_act integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('sequence_name')
      first_name text NOT NULL,
      last_name text NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT actors_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_act)
    );
   ```
3. If you have sequence, use the sequence in the insert query

   ```
     CREATE TABLE actors (
       id_act integer,
       first_name text NOT NULL,
       last_name text NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT actors_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_act)
     ); 


   INSERT INTO actors (id_act, first_name, last_name) VALUES (nextval('sequence_name'), 'Tom', 'Hanks');
   ```